Is it possible to make \AddToHook{cmd/caption/before} work with the caption package?
In the following, I'm adding a label to a caption thanks to \AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}. This works well, except if the caption package is used:

LaTeX Warning: Reference `foo1' on page 1 undefined on input line 25.

\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{caption}
\AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}{\label{foo1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
  \label{foo2}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{foo1} and~\ref{foo2}.
\end{document}

Is there a solution so that this also works when the caption package is loaded?
Same problem and same question for the subcaption package.
Edit
The use case is the following: for a class I'm working on, I've created a \credit{⟨credit⟩} command that, if inserted by the user at the beginning of a figure environment, will lists the ⟨credit⟩ of the figure in a list of credits automatically added at the end of the document. And, transparently for the user, I've added bi-directional links between such credited figures and their corresponding credit: this has been done by automatically creating a unique pair of labels \g__idm_credit_anchor_label_tl and \g__idm_credit_target_label_tl and, in my real use case, the code is the following:
\AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}{
  \bool_if:nT {\g__idm_credit_bool} {
    \label{\g__idm_credit_anchor_label_tl}
  }
}

where the boolean \g__idm_credit_bool is set to true when a \credit{⟨credit⟩} command is used in a figure environment.

May I ask what the reasoning or usecase is here?

why would you want a label before the caption?

@daleif Use case added.

Why don't you add the hypertarget inside of the \credit definition?

@Skillmon That's the case, thanks to something like \exp_not:N \item[\MakeLinkTarget*{\g__idm_credit_target_label_tl}{\zcref[capfirst]{\g__idm_credit_anchor_label_tl}}] (zref-clever involved).

@DenisBitouzé Not the question itself, but about the use case. Unless you need to print the credits list before the figures, since you control both sides there, you don't even need to use \labels. You can: i) step a unique counter/int; ii) use \MakeLinkTarget based on that "id"; iii) store the "id" in a seq var; iv) map through the seq to print the list at the end, again using \MakeLinkTarget for the backlink. That's more or less what, e.g., postnotes does for endnotes, you can check how it handles the two way links. If you don't need to tamper with \caption that'd be a bonus. ;-)

@gusbrs Interesting trick! I'll try to find time to implement it.

Maybe you can try
\AddToHook{cmd/@caption/after}{\label{foo1}}

It seems to work with, or without, the caption package (not fully tested, though).
Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\AddToHook{cmd/@caption/after}{\label{foo1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
  \label{foo2}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{foo1} and~\ref{foo2}.
\end{document}



That does indeed the trick, thanks! FWIW, my real usecase involves also the zref-titleref package which, if loaded after caption, causes the compilation to fail; if it is loaded before, everything works nicely.

@DenisBitouzé relying on internal commands is ok in a single document but is not something that you should do in a class.

@UlrikeFischer In case packages loaded by the class also change the behavior of such internal commands?

@DenisBitouzé internal commands can change, they are no documented user interface. (Generally it is not clear what your label should actually label, the caption/before in your question and the @caption/after-version in this answer do quite different things.)

@DenisBitouzé Regarding zref-titleref/caption load order, see: https://github.com/ho-tex/zref/issues/21. You may wish to chime in and help me convince Ulrike to provide the name property/module. ;-)  But, failing that, and regardless of that, in a class you could create a property which does the same (with a more "internal sounding name" I guess) and use it, thus getting rid of this load order problem.

A common user error is to put the \label before the \caption and then complain that the reference points e.g. to the previous section:
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \label{foo1}
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
  \label{foo2}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{foo1} and~\ref{foo2}.
\end{document}


The caption package contains code to prevent this user error, and makes \labels issued in a figure before a caption command undefined:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  Foobar
  \label{foo1}
  \caption{Foobar's caption}
  \label{foo2}
\end{figure}
See Figure~\ref{foo1} and~\ref{foo2}.
\end{document}



I'm aware of this common error but, as shown by the MCE in my question, the problem doesn't arise with \AddToHook{cmd/caption/before}, I guess because this hook is executed at the very start of the command and not before. And \AddToHook{cmd/caption/after} doesn't work (as told in the ltcmdhooks documentation).

Using the hook makes no difference (I would be very surprised if it would). In any case you are running here into a feature of caption, so open an issue at its gitlab and ask for some option to avoid this label test.

Indeed, you're right: it doesn't work with my MCE; but it is working in my real use case. Quite strange...

I have given up using \AddToHook{cmd/caption/before} and resorted to \NewCommandCopy and \RenewDocumentCommand\caption{O{} m }{...}.
